# No module named msg

Tags: ros, rosserial, arduino#ros#raspberry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using an Arduino Uno with a Raspberry Pi on ROS indigo.
When I run this command :  `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py`

I don't understand why I get this error message :

`> pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws/src $ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 40, in 
import rosserial_python


File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/__ init__ .py", line 35, in 
exec(__fh.read())


File "<'string'>", line 1, in <'module'>


File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 47, in <'module'>


from rosserial_msgs.msg import *


ImportError : No module named msg`

And I also don't understand where my script is looking for when running 'from rosserial_msgs.msg import*' line in python.
In :

- /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_msgs/msg

Or in :

- /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Or somewhere else ?

Regards,

Matthieu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259005/no-module-named-msg/) by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that you have run catkin_make inside the catkin_ws directory. If you have already done that, I suspect that you have not added your catkin_ws in your bashrc. If you haven't, just run the following command:

```
echo "source /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> /home/pi/.bashrc
```

Then close all terminals or run (on each open terminal):

```
source /home/pi/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on 2017-04-12**:
Thanks you very much. It works!

I missed   `>> /home/pi/.bashrc`

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-12**:
Glad I helped! Don't forget to mark the question as solved, to help others too!